# How to use flare binary files in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter

How can I use flare binary files (.flr) in my flutter app?

Comment: If there is no package can find from pub.dartlang.org you can write it by native by using [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flare_flutter) is exactly what you need

Answer (score 3):

```
    FlareActor(
    "location/00.flr",
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    animation: // "here you set the name of the animations tab", 
    ),
```

for example here https://www.2dimensions.com/a/pollux/files/flare/success-check
the name of animation is Untitled

Answer (score 0):

How about you check the docs https://pub.dev/packages/flare_flutter

You can create your own flare file by signing in on https://www.2dimensions.com/
if your currently trying experimenting with someone else's flare file.

Assuming that you have an existing project,

1. Add the package to your project's dependencies (pubspec.yaml)
2. Check the docs(above link) and see which files you really need and import them accordingly

   import 'package:flarecode/flare_actor.dart';

You'll surely need the above one.

3. Paste the files within your project directory and don't forget to mention it in pubspec.yaml.
   (Optional)
4. Make sure you have some way to trigger the animation using FlareController (Raised Animation or as soon as the widget is built)

Example Code:

```
Container(
    FlareActor(
    "assets/yourflare",
    alignment:Alignment.center,
    fit:BoxFit.contain,
    animation:"idle"  /* Default_Animation_Name (One Flare file can hold multiple flare animations with the same name) */ ) );
```